# What is enroll key from disk, enroll hash from disk and enroll Mok after Ubuntu 18.10 installation

Tags: 18.10

After I installed Ubuntu 18.10, it asked me to remove my USB stick and hit enter. Then, it asked me if I enroll Mok, key from disk and hash from disk. What are they? What am I supposed to do?

Comment: This is for signing drivers that the system wants to load but is prevented to do so by the Secure Boot ON setting at UEFI. It's much easier to just disable that.

Comment: After I disabled Secure Boot and reinstalled Ubuntu, these questions did not show up. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

When you are in Ubuntu 20.04 installation process tap the password for SECURE BOOT. Then in first reboot choose ENROLL MOK, and enter your SECURE BOOT password. It will let all special proprietary drivers work properly. The secure boot password you need to enter once only. Then everything will be simplier. Dont worry, be happy.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu and thank you for contributing. Please take the [tour]. When posting your insights please avoid irrelevant text such as "Don't worry, be happy".

Comment: Warning: I encountered problems when typing secure boot password: I had to use numpad to enter password digits, despite the fact I DIDN'T use numpad in the first place when creating password! Also I have a belgian keyboard: not sure if it's an issue. Long story short, typing password when enrolling MOK is not easy and this should probably be improved... (Context: installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on second SSD, with Windows 11 already present on First SSD)