# Installed Ubuntu 23.10 but I'm unable to start my PC after a few days

Tags: software-installation, 23.10, moklistrt

I installed the Ubuntu 23.10. It was working well for a few days, but later I couldn't use my PC anymore. It is showing the following MokListRT  errors.

```
Could not Create MokListRT: Volume Full 
Could not Create MokListRT: Volume Full 
Could not Create MokListRT: Volume Full 
Could not Create MokListTrustedRT: Volume Full
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed: Volume Full
```

Well, I don't have a correct answer ! A correct correction ? or application to solve your bugs !

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401737/couldnt-create-moklist-volume-full-grub-doesnt-start-at-all). Hope it helps.