Moklist Full Error & is it a listed bug
Following on from a question that was asked by another MokListRT error: volume full - delete and reinstall keys ...
I am getting this on startup...
Could not create MokListRT: Volume Full
Could not create MokListXRT: Volume Full
Could not create MokListTrustRT: Volume Full
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed: Volume Full
and the PC powers off.
Clearing out the BIOS DBX keys gets me through once, but then I get...
EFI stub: WARNING: Failed to measure data for event 1: 0x800000000000000b
although it still lets me through.

I thought that this problem may have already been listed as a bug. However, I am no longer sure. The fix I gave works, but must be applied EVERY TIME I need to boot the machine, which is getting tiresome.
I'm using secure boot on an intel 6700K machine (Asus H170M-Plus m/board & no video card) with Ubuntu 24.04.
To fix the problem, I have tried: 

replacing the SSD & doing a fresh install 
plus shorting the reset jumper on the motherboard 
and shorting the battery connectors to reset everything. 
reinstalling the same bios update (no more bios update support) over the M/board

... nothing seems to fix it permanently and I don't want to disable secure boot.
I'm beginning to wonder whether it is a mishandling of a full list as a fatal error or whether the NVRAM just can't handle all those keys.
There are 2 questions here... how to fix permanently? ... and if it is inherent in the O/S how do I get it listed as a bug or even check if it already is a listed bug.

Update:
so far, I've tried:

a fresh install on a new ssd
reloading the same bios update
removed all efibootmgr entries except the install
checked Moklist for only one key
ran update-grub to update the boot menu
shorted the jumper on the motherboard to wipe the cmos
shorted the contacts for the batter for about 1 hour
pulled the battery out for nearly 48 hours
replaced the battery with a new one (it couldn't hurt)


Update 2:
I've continued to try fixes.. it probably is a garbage collection issue.
However, I have also tried replacing the SSD and installing windows 7
Then formatting and installing windows 10.
All in the hopes that they would trigger the garbage collection... but no. Those O/S work fine though.  Just Ubuntu that seems to have a problem.
I even reformatted again, installed 24.04 and upgraded to a beta version of 24.10 to see if the next version addresses it.. nope.
I don't think this is similar to Couldn't Create Moklist: Volume Full - grub doesn't start at all as I am not dual booting, replaced the entire SSD and created a fresh installation. The solution of removing all the additional boot options did not work.

That is a Microsoft error message. Nothing to do with Ubuntu.

How can that be Microsoft when I use a fresh SSD, clean install and am not dual booting and reset the motherboard?

see if one of the answers work for you https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401737/couldnt-create-moklist-volume-full-grub-doesnt-start-at-all

This question is similar to: How do I report a bug?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If searching Launchpad doesn't show any bug reports that are a close enough match, then report it. If it has already been reported, the devs will mark it as a duplicate.

thanks karel, I've updated the question to show that I'm not dual booting and the solution that the other question offers does not work. That and I don't want to disable secure boot.
